# request.getattribute are null and some are having data

Tags: java, jsp, setattribute

Is there any limit in number of set attributes you can use in java ?

Because i am trying to set attributes in java and request them in JSP page.

when i see the console i can see the values are being set(by using system.out.println(obj)) but at JSP some attributes are having data and some are null even though data set wasn't null.

any suggestions ?

```
if (desc.equalsIgnoreCase("DiastolicBp")) {
    System.out.println(uom.getUnitsOfMeasure());
    List<String> dbpUom = new ArrayList();
    dbpUom.add(Double.toString(uom.getMaxValue()));
    dbpUom.add(Double.toString(uom.getMinValue()));
    dbpUom.add(uom.getUnitsOfMeasure());
    request.setAttribute("dbpUom",dbpUom);

}
```

at jsp page:

${dbpUom[2]}

Comment: You need to show us your JSP page. Which attribute you are trying to get, that gives you `null` output?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any limit in number of set attributes you can use in java ?

The the only limit is the size of the program's heap.  If you run into that limit (due to setting too many attributes, or for any other reason) you will get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

On the specifics of your problem, you have not provided enough information to know what might be happening.

Comment: i didnt receive any errors: but for more info: i am using the set attrib in get function of servlet ? is there any limitation in get function ?